# will dual-boot (windows 10 & kubuntu) work with rEFind?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader, refind

I changed the SSD on my laptop and I've installed Windows 10 on it,
Now I also want to install kubuntu on my laptop.
Before that I had grub bootloader, windows 10 and kubuntu.
Now I wonder if I should use rEFind instead of grub, but I am not sure if it will fit dual boot of Windows and Linux.
I have read this post
[Any downside to using rEFInd instead of GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760875/any-downside-to-using-refind-instead-of-grub#760971)

But I'm still worried because I've seen some places that said that rEFind will not work with bios based systems.
Does that mean I sing have access to the bios on my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to let the Ubuntu installer automatically install grub on any type of SSD. Even if one of the OSs in the dual boot doesn't boot the first time after installing Ubuntu, it's usually possible to repair grub by running the [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) application.

Links:

- [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/q/217904/)
- [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/708247/)
- [Add Windows 10 to GRUB OS list](https://askubuntu.com/q/661947)
- [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/q/88384)
- [Problem with dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1200577)

Comment: Thanks, would it work find with rEFind?

Comment: Repairing the bootloader with rEFInd is sometimes a manual process. It's not always automatically done by a GUI application, so you've got to hustle.